# How to initiate Nivo Slider in ajax loaded content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, nivo-slider

I am having trouble getting Nivo slider to initiate when the page containing it had been loaded by ajax.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="work">
  <img class="introPic" src="images/thumb.jpg" width="250" height="99" />
    <h3><img class="arrow" src="images/arrow_open.gif" alt="&gt;" /> <a class="titlelink" href="testcontent4.html" rel="address:testcontent4.html">Nivo Slider Project</a></h3>
    <div class="projectIntro">
    <p>This is some intro text for Nivo Slider Project</p>
    </div>
   <div class="pictures"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery

```
$(function(){

   function close_other() {
   var selected_work = $('.selected_work');

    selected_work.children('.pictures').empty();
    $('.selected_work img.arrow').attr("src", "images/arrow_open.gif");
    selected_work.removeClass("selected_work");
 }

  $('div.work a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
  $('div.work').bind('click', function() {

$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 500);

var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href'),
    lastPart = href.split('/'),
    hash = lastPart[lastPart.length - 1];

window.location.hash = hash;

var parent = $(this);
var content_holder = parent.children(".pictures");

if (parent.hasClass("selected_work")) {
    close_other();
    return;
}

close_other();

parent.addClass("selected_work");

content_holder.load(href + ' #ajaxContent', function() {

$(this).find('#slider').nivoSlider({

        effect:'fade', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        animSpeed:300,
        pauseTime:4000,
        controlNav:true,
        pauseOnHover:true //Stop animation while hovering
    });

}); 


    $('.selected_work img.arrow').attr("src", "images/arrow_close.gif");
  });
});
```

Here is a live demo: http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/clicktest/divclicknivotest.html
The "Nivo Slider Project" is the one I want to get working...

Probably doing something basic wrong as i am new to jQuery so would appreciate any help you can give.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem here was not the code, but a conflict between an older version of Nivo Slider and the current version of jQuery (1.7.1). When I went back to jQuery 1.4.2 it worked. Then I updated Nivo Slider to the latest version with the current jQuery and it also worked.

Answer (score 0):

inside your .work a function, try this. Note however, that you must use the correct nivo slider html structure for `.pictures`.

```
$('div.work').click(function(e) { 
  $('.pictures').show();
  $('.pictures').data('nivoslider').stop().start; //Stop the Slider if it's currently running, then start it.
  e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Catfish - I tried that - unlike the previous version it loads all the pictures, but not as a slideshow http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/clicktest/divclicknivotest2.html  - I also tried putting $('.pictures').data('nivoslider').stop().start; }); after content_holder.load(href + ' #ajaxContent', function() { - this seems to trigger the nivo loader but the images do not load - http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/clicktest/divclicknivotest3.html

Comment: Correction - clicking on div.work a loads testcontent4.html to a new page - that's why you see all the images. Please bear in mind that div.work a is not the link - the jquery above makes div.work the clickable div (that's why I tried your code after content_holder.load(href + ' #ajaxContent', function() {

Comment: I've edited my answer. Why don't you try initially having all your images in the .pictures div and have the css for .pictures as display: none. Then when div.work is clicked, have the images appear and have the nivo slider start.

Comment: I can't do that unfortunately as I will have a lot of projects and the point of the ajax is so the data only loads as needed - if I put all the images in the .pictures divs the page would have too large a file size and be slow. I actually got it working using my original code above - turns out it was an issue with the new version of jquery - when I downgraded to 1.4.2 it worked! (I had similar code working before so I looked at the differences between what I had then and what I had now and the only difference seemed to be the query version) Appreciate you taking the time to help though, Thanks