# .load a <div id='slider'> into empty div works fine, but creates a <div id='slider'> at bottom of the page, not sure why

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

Im using .load to load (when clicked) a nivo slider and a small bit of text into a empty div at the top of the page. It all works fine but when it loads it also loads an empty slider div bellow the footer, i could just hide this by making the giving the page a max-height but id like to get to find out what is causing this.

the page in question is [new.pudle.co.uk](http://new.pudle.co.uk) if you click on one of the pink tiles it will open load the slider and at the same time put the empty div at the bottom.

The js im using is

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
$("#pegasus-tile, #o-w").click(function(){
    $("#proj-content").load("projects/pegasus.html", function(){

        $('<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>').appendTo($('body'));
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({effect: 'sliceUpDown'}),

        $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#proj-content").load("projects/blank.html"),


        $("#next-pegasus").click(function(){
        $("#proj-content").load("projects/bgapp.html");


            }); 
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `$('<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>').appendTo($('body'));`
will add `<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>` just before the `</body>` tag...

Comment: So where did you want the div to appear? (Bear in mind you're creating multiple `div` elements with the same `id`.)

Comment: i ment for it to go the "empty div" #proj-content  would just removing `.appendTo($('body'))` sort it ?

Comment: I don't think you need that entire line. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the line

```
$('<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>').appendTo($('body'));
```

cos you have

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<img src="images/projects/pegasus property/1.png" width="490" height="400" />
<img src="images/projects/pegasus property/2.png" width="490" height="400" />
</div><!--slider close-->
```

in `projects/pegasus.html`, hence two sliders are appearing, and the one added by jquery is at the bottom.

Did you add this cos the nivoSlider didn't work without that or something?

Also I notice you have a `google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {` for every pink box... This may not turn out to be very maintainable (ok I assume you are just testing at the moment, but better to get it 'right' the first time. Maybe add a common class to each pink box, then use its id to work out what content to load.

Comment: yep, i couldnt get the nivoSlider to work with out this, by the way thanks for all the imput on this i realy appreciate it

Comment: Right ok. Must be something to do with nivoSlider. I would take out the entire `appendTo` line then have a play. Hard to make any more suggestions without downloading your website to have a play with...

Are you using the most recent version of nivoSlider? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388776/how-to-initiate-nivo-slider-in-ajax-loaded-content suggests that may be the problem

Also he uses `$(this).find('#slider').nivoSlider({`... Try that maybe

Comment: taking out the .appendTo($('body')) line did the trick, cheers

Answer (score 0):

That is what

```
$('<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>').appendTo($('body'));
```

does.. it adds a slider at the bottom of the body..

What were you expecting ? (*oh, and you are adding one on each click..*)